# problems with button added in javascript

Tags: javascript

The following code successfully adds a button to a form every time I click a button with id "button0". But firebug gives me the error

```
form1 is null
[Break On This Error]   

form1.appendChild(element);
```

And the new button will not execute the function "foo()" despite the fact that it's been
set to its onclick value. Here's the code

```
var counter = 0;

function add(){
  counter++;
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.type = "button";
  element.value = "test";
  element.name = "button"+counter;
  element.id = "button"+ counter;
  element.onclick="foo()";
  var form1 = document.getElementById("form1");
  var body1 = document.getElementById("b1");
  var header = document.getElementById("header");
  form1.appendChild(element);
  header.innerHTML = "Two Buttons";
};

function foo(){
  var butt =   document.getElementById("button1");
  butt.value = "works";
  console.log("works");
};

add();
```

I also get a firebug error (undefined) if I use 
    document.form1.appendChild(element);

The funny thing is I DO get the new button every time I click. It's just that the button doesn't work.

Here's my html

```
<body id = "b1">

<script src = "button-in-code.js"></script>
<h1 id = "header">Buttons</h1>
<form id = "form1" name = "form1">
<input type="button" id = "button0" name="sel" value="Select all" onclick="add()">
</form>

<hr>
<address></address>
<!-- hhmts start -->Last modified: Mon Jul  8 10:07:26 EDT 2013 <!-- hhmts end -->
</body> </html>
```

Comment: Could you add your HTML?  Since most of the issue seems to be that it's not finding the element named `form1`, this may be an html issue.  It may also help to set this up on a site like jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com

Comment: You have to assign a function to `.onclick`, not a string.

Comment: I hope you are calling this code on DOM ready.

Comment: Here's my HTML:<body id = "b1">

    <script src = "button-in-code.js"></script>
    <h1 id = "header">Buttons</h1>
    <form id = "form1" name = "form1">
    <input type="button" id = "button0" name="sel" value="Select     all" onclick="add()">
    </form>

<hr>
<address></address>
<!-- hhmts start -->Last modified: Mon Jul  8 10:07:26 EDT 2013 <!-- hhmts end -->
</body> </html>

Comment: if I remove the quotes around the function in the definition of onclick the code stops working: it doesn't create a new button.

Comment: If you just remove the quotes, then you are *calling* the function and assign its return value to `onclick`, instead of assigning the function itself. Please have a look at the question I linked to and at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html. Also note that changing the value of the element `#button1` only works if the button exists.

Comment: See it "working": http://jsfiddle.net/ULkxt/.

Answer (score 0):

Try add the `<script src = "button-in-code.js"></script>` after the html code with `<form>...</form>`.

Because the `add();` function is executed automatically, the javascript code must be added after the html elements which are used in that function.

Comment: CoursesWeb's answer fixed the execution of add()! Thanks. The only problem I have left is that the new buttons won't execute foo() when clicked.

Comment: The relevant code line should be `element.onclick=foo;`. Note that this is not the preferred method of attaching event listeners. I would recommend using a JS library to streamline the event handling (among other issues) across browsers.